# Reading the LDAP security principal

Tags: java, ldap

I have a string I get from a X509Certificate on the form

> UID=A unique id,CN=Common name,C=country code, ST=state

To me that looks ldap'ish, and then I thought that maybe there exists an LDAP API for java that can tokenize this string for me, so I maybe get a map with the name as key and the content as value - or something similar.
Does this exists?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right after I posted my question, I decided to take one last look at the java API - and guess what I found: LdapName. Hat class does what I did and it even validates the input.

So now I got the following code:

```
 LdapName ldapName = new LdapName(dn);
 List<Rdn>  distinguishedNames = ldapName.getRdns();

 for (Rdn rdn : distinguishedNames) {
     if ("c".equals(name.getType().toLowerCase())) {
         country = (String) name.getValue();
     }
     ...
 }
```

Comment: You might find the [UnboundID LDAP SDK](http://www.unboundid.com/products/ldap-sdk/) much easier to use.

Answer (score 1):

There are at least two Java APIs built in: `javax.naming.NameParser` derived from an LDAP `Context`, which yields a `javax.naming.Name`; and `javax.naming.ldap.LdapName`.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know of any tokenizer for it. You might "abuse" `java.util.Properites` for it, which is based on a Map:

```
String cert = "UID=A unique id,CN=Common name,C=country code, ST=state";
cert = cert.replaceAll(",", "\n");
Properties props = new Properties();
props.load(new StringReader(cert));

System.out.println(props.getProperty("UID"));
System.out.println(props.getProperty("CN"));
System.out.println(props.getProperty("C"));
System.out.println(props.getProperty("ST"));
```

Comment: I was looking for a solution that takes into consideration that a comma could occur in value. Hoping to find an LDAP API.

Comment: Won't work, as it doesn't recognize LDAP escaping. Consider e.g. an escaped comma. And there are at least two solutions in the JDK.